# InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'database/table'. Mariadb 10.1.40

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Generally server works fine without any issues. But recently I enabled error logs to test few things and I noticed an error

```
InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'database/table'.
```

This has a reference to a very old database that was in the server and which has been manually deleted for some unknown reason. Few have asked to delete the aria_log_ files but it didn't make any difference. With the error it gives a link to mariadb site but it is not related to this exact issue.

I just want to clean this stale data somewhere recorded in mariadb so the error will go away. What needs to be done to clean this mess?

Comment: is it new? you didn't post a timestamp. this error occurs when the server can not access the folder, so check if the rights are ok or if the flder specified in my.conf exists, also check the system logs if there is something

Comment: the particular database in question has been long gone... since error log was not enabled it was not visible. Once i enabled the log I saw this. Since server skips this , server starts ok and operates normaly. So that's why others haven't noticed it before. I just want to remove these references.

Comment: you would notice because mysql/mariadb needs that to access and save data.

Comment: Understood. But actual problem i want to solve is that this error which refers to old/missing database. I am not trying to recover the database this error refers to. I just want to clean up this orphaned references so that mysql will not fill up error log with this anymore

Comment: did you check the sub forlder in the data directory, if there are empty folders?

Comment: There is no folder related to this database at all. Because it has been physically deleted and no backups or anything. It has been used to test something and accidentally deleted the folder. So if there are any quries to remove these reference from mysql system this should go away and am sure there must be a way to do this.

Comment: i would run check tables and if that doesn't help a recovery, but as i never done such a think this i never seen

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need data in the corrupt table, you can drop it by first discarding the tablespace:

```
ALTER TABLE actor DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

after that you can drop the table itself:

```
DROP TABLE actor;
```

In case the first step is not working, first replace actor.ibd file with a copy from an empty table with the same structure.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html)